# How do you read a registry value using a custom msbuild task?

Tags: msbuild, registry, msbuild-task

I'm creating an MSBuild task that will read the registry for a specific registry key.  If I write the same line of code (see below) in a console application, it returns the expected result, but when it is within the MSBuild task, it returns nothing.

```
Return Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\", "SQLPath", Nothing)
```

I would expect the above code to return `Nothing` if the key/value pair doesn't exist, and return the value if it does exist.  I am getting `Nothing` when the MSBuild task gets executed.  Is there some attribute that I need to apply to the Execute function of the MSBuild task to tell it that it needs to read the registry?

**EDIT:**

Here is what is being executed from the MSBuild task:

```
Return Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\", "SQLPath", Nothing)
```

I beleive this to be caused by the [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(VS.85).aspx) on my Vista x64 machine running MSBuild in 32bit.  Is there any way that you can tell the custom MSBuild task (written in VB .Net) to look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\` then only if nothing exists there then look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\`?

Thank you,

Scott Blue

Comment: have you tried a tool like RegMon to make sure that you're reading the right registry key when it's hit from MSBuild?  Might be some 32-bit/64-bit munging going on?

Comment: Good thought, I'll have a look at that...

Comment: So, `RegMon` is replaced by `Process Monitor` and it reports that when I use the console application to read the registry it is a successful read via TestingRegistry.exe (Program Name).  But when I run the task, it uses shows devenv.exe as the calling application and is actually trying to open this key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup` and getting a `NAME NOT FOUND` error.  Why would it add in a `Wow6432Node` element into the path?

Comment: It seems that the answer is dealing with going from 32 bit to 64 bit calling applications.  This MSDN article shows someone with the same issue (or maybe the exact opposite, but still same issue).  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/8afb06cf-2010-4b34-9a07-be20d43ea696  I think `great_llama` is on the right track.

Comment: Wow6432Node is the 32-bit 'registry sandbox' when running 32-bit apps on 64-bit OS.  You'll find all of your 32-bit app registry queries redirected here; it's automatic and AFAIK you can't not do it.  You might need to create a 64-bit component or pop out to a shell to run the check; it will not be redirected.  Not sure how all that would link together.

Answer (score 18):

You can read the registry directly from MSBuild, without a custom task, like this:

```
$(registry:Hive\MyKey\MySubKey@Value)
```

E.g.,

```
$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\)
```

You said that you're looking to do this from a custom task, so this may not apply, but I'm posting it in case it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Our msbuild script runs from an x86 Visual Studio Command Prompt.  It does not read the 64 bit registry when using this syntax.  It there a different syntax which would allow the x86 to read the 64 bit registry?

Answer (score 0):

How about using VB's [If()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) ternary function?

```
Function GetSqlPathFromReg() As Object
    Return If(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\", "SQLPath", Nothing), _
              Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\", "SQLPath", Nothing))
End Function
```

Assuming you have an `Output()` property:

```
Private _sqlPath As String

<Output()> _
Public ReadOnly Property SqlPath() As String
    Get
        Return _sqlPath
    End Get
End Property
```

Then all you have to do is calling it from the `Execute()` method:

```
_sqlPath = GetSqlPathFromReg().ToString()
```

Comment: Good thought, but doesn't work.  Because of the Registry Redirector, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\` gets turned into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\`automatically, thus your solution would effectively be:  
    `Return If(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\", "SQLPath", Nothing), _
              Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\", "SQLPath", Nothing))`

Wow6432Node is injected automatically.

Comment: Maybe you just need to look in a different location, see this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936491